# 12 Leads ECG Drawing

Tags: .net-core, d3.js, chart.js

I want to draw a 12 Leads ECG Drawing using d3 JS library but failed to show 12 leads (4 leads per row). I Want to have any suitable JS library (Subscription is ok) that helps me do that. Here is the sample of 12 leads ECG in the picture below

[image: example needed]

[image: example number 2]

The first picture is the actual 12 leads ECG that I need to draw. Using d3js library I'm able to do the no 2 picture which contains only one leads. Can anyone one find any suitable JS library or .net core packages that can do the same as first picture?